# Why is there no Gezeirah against a Jew sharing food with a non-Jew (similar to the idea of Bishul Akum)?

Tags: intermarriage, bishul-akum

[Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Bishul_Akum) writes on the prohibition of food cooked by non-Jews (Bishul Akum)

> There are a number of reasons for this gezeirah. The opinion of [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.16a.17?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Beitzah.16a.17.1&lang2=bi)
> is that chazal wanted to prevent socializing with non-Jews, which
> might lead to intermarriage (chasnus).  [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.38a.1?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Avodah_Zarah.38a.1.1&lang2=bi) in Meseches Avodah Zarah
> says that we are concerned that if the Jew often eats the non-Jew's
> food, the non-Jew might later serve a non-kosher food item to the Jew.
> Most poskim agree with the first reason.

If the accepted reason is to prevent intermarriage, should there not be another prohibition, that is a Jew should not cook food for a non-Jew which equally might lead to socializing with non-Jews, and intermarriage?  Let there then be a gezeirah on Jewish people not to share their food with non-Jews?

Comment: But isn't the gezeirah on the status of the food? The food is unacceptable to the Jew because of the concern over later behaviors. Are you suggesting that the food become inedible for the Jew who cooked it because of its possible use or that the non-Jew be bound by a Jewish law regarding the status of the food? Or are you asking about a broader injunction against socializing and intermarrying (which might already exist)?

Comment: Wouldn't the parallel be that the gentile can't eat food cooked by a Jew? Is there rabbinic prohibitions like that on a gentile?

Comment: בשביל חנופה שהחניפו לקרח על עסקי לגימה. סנהדרין נב ע׳א. The one who feeds brings the eater towards the feeder's perspective

Comment: @rosends Good point. I am not concerned with the status of the food for the non-Jew nor do I suggest that Chazal made a gezeirah applicable to the the non-Jew. I am concerned with following the reason behind Bishul Akum which should find expression in an "injunction against socializing". Can you quote such an injunction please?

Comment: @user6591 If you can back up your interpretation of the text, you have the beginnings of an answer. Sefaria translates the whole phrase in the Gemoro, "It means that because of the flattery of those people who flattered Korah over matters of eating, i.e., because of the food and drink that he would give them, the minister of Gehenna gnashed his teeth over them, as they eventually sinned and fell into his hands."

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify it in the light of some of the comments.

Comment: other prohibitions to prevent socializing: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Socializing_with_Non-Jews